# How to download files in bulk and rename them from a list of names

Tags: powershell, download

I am looking for a way download mp4 files from a list of sites and rename them based off a list of names since I cant use  the URLs, they are way too long and complex.

Is there a way to download these files and name them according to a separate list I have

```
$Videos= get-content "C:\temp\VidList.txt"
$VideoNames = Get-Content "C:\temp\NameList.txt"


foreach ($site in $Videos){
$uri= $site 
$file='F:\CEH Saved videos\test\test.mp4'
$wc=New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$wc.DownloadFile($uri,$file)




}
```

Comment: please provide a few lines from the `NameList.txt` file AND the content of the `$Videos` variable. that way folks can test against actual data instead of simply making wild guesses ... [*grin*]

Comment: i cant due to access restriction sorry.  but each line is a just a url and the download works when I hard code a name fine however im not looking to do that.

Comment: i don't see anything obviously wrong with your code. however, without any test data, i can't test to see what needs changing. sorry ... [*sigh ...*]

Comment: im sorry some of the formatting was off in the post and missed a part. I edited it now. maybe i'm not being clear. I want where it says "test.mp4"  to be with the names in the list.  the list contains "video1 video 2 video3..." etc all are on separate lines.  I want this to basically - Grab this file and rename it with the names in this list.

Comment: so you want to match the URL in the `$Videos` list with the new name in the `$VideoNames` list? PLEASE post a _sanitized sample of each file_. they have no need to be real, just need to be _realistic_.

Comment: At the moment, your code is hardcoding the filename, so effectively overwriting it continuously. At least tell what is in the `"C:\temp\NameList.txt"` and if there are the same or more filename alternatives in there as there are sites in `C:\temp\VidList.txt`. Why such an elaborate scheme in the first place. Wouldn't it be far easier to append a sequence number for each file downloaded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As commented, your code now keeps using the same file name and is not using the alternatives in "C:\temp\NameList.txt" at all.

Also, we don't know if this file contains complete path and filenames or just the names without the path..

Assuming you have full names in there, use this:

```
$Videos     = Get-Content -Path "C:\temp\VidList.txt"
$VideoNames = Get-Content -Path "C:\temp\NameList.txt"

# make sure there are at least the same amount of filenames
$totalVideos = [math]::Min($Videos.Count, $VideoNames.Count)

# create the Webclient object above the loop only once
$wc = New-Object System.Net.WebClient

for ($i = 0; $i -lt $totalVideos; $i++) {
    $uri  = $Videos[$i]
    $file = $VideoNames[$i]
    $wc.DownloadFile($uri,$file)
}
$wc.Dispose()
```

If you only have filenames without path in `C:\temp\NameList.txt` and all files should go to the same output folder, use this instead:

```
$Videos       = Get-Content -Path "C:\temp\VidList.txt"
$VideoNames   = Get-Content -Path "C:\temp\NameList.txt"
$outputFolder = 'F:\CEH Saved videos\test'
# make sure there are at least the same amount of filenames
$totalVideos = [math]::Min($Videos.Count, $VideoNames.Count)

# create the Webclient object above the loop only once
$wc = New-Object System.Net.WebClient

for ($i = 0; $i -lt $totalVideos; $i++) {
    $uri  = $Videos[$i]
    $file = Join-Path -Path $outputFolder -ChildPath $VideoNames[$i]
    $wc.DownloadFile($uri,$file)
}
$wc.Dispose()
```

---

**Edit**

Seeing your latest comment, the files should be named `Video1`, `Vide2` etc.
I that case this would be easier and you don't have to use the 'C:\temp\NameList.txt' file

```
$Videos       = Get-Content -Path "C:\temp\VidList.txt"
$outputFolder = 'F:\CEH Saved videos\test'

# create the Webclient object above the loop only once
$wc = New-Object System.Net.WebClient

for ($i = 0; $i -lt $Videos.Count; $i++) {
    $uri  = $Videos[$i]
    $file = Join-Path -Path $outputFolder -ChildPath ("Video{0:00}.mp4" -f ($i + 1))
    $wc.DownloadFile($uri,$file)
}
$wc.Dispose()
```